# I want no text left or right from my centered list. How?

Tags: jquery, html, list, text

I am using a centered list `<li>` in my website. The list takes up 70% of the width. The problem I have now is that the text, written below it shows up on the right of the list. How do I avoid this?

I do not want to just put `<br />` in front of the text, because the site is responsive and it would mess up the mobile view. I also do not want to use a div width a fixed height on the right, because it would again cause problems with the mobile view.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered setting up a fiddle so that we can look at the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your LI elements a display attribute of `block`